# Dict using FOR LOOP

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm a little bit confused about how to create a number of dicts using a for loop and append those dicts to a list.

```
object_1 = dict()
object_1['ID'] = 1234
object_1['NAME'] = 'ACB'
...
object_2 = dict()
object_2['ID'] = 123
object_2['NAME'] = 'ABC'
...

object_list = list()
object_list.append(object_1)
object_list.append(object_2)
```

I want to create *x* dict objects where *x* is the number of rows from my SELECT.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM account WHERE date=current_date") 
rows = cur.fetchall()

i=0
for row in rows:
...
#What I thought
i += 1
obj_+i = dict()
obj_+i['ID'] = row[0]
....
....
obj_list = list()
obj_list.append(obj_+i)
```

Comment: Does your indentation really looks like that?

Comment: This is just a example :]

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job

```
object_list = []
for row in rows:
    object_list.append({'ID': row[0], 'NAME': row[1]})
```

Comment: It worked! However, when I print my list, the elements is not being shown in order, example: instead "ID", "NAME", "CITY" | "NAME"; "CITY"... and how can i access just "NAME"? object_list["NAME"] ?

Comment: @TMoraes Dictionaries don't have order. You can use a list comprehension: `[o["NAME"] for o in object_list]`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the trick:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM account WHERE date=current_date") 
rows = cur.fetchall()

obj_list = []
for row in rows:
    d = {}
    d['ID'] = row[0]
    ...
    obj_list.append(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use string concatenation to create variable variable names like that -- and you don't need to, either. You can just reuse the same variable name again and again in the loop and add the newly created object to the list. Reusing the same variable name in the next iteration of the loop will not change the object previously assigned to that variable.

Also, note that you should move the list initialization `obj_list = list()` outside of the loop, otherwise you will reset the list in each iteration.

```
obj_list = list()
for row in rows:
    obj = dict()
    obj['ID'] = row[0]
    ...
    obj_list.append(obj)
```

If you want to access the individual dictionaries in the list after the loop, you can use e.g. `obj_list[0]` to get `obj_1`, `obj_list[1]` for `obj_2`, and so on.